# How does a web browser determine the z-index if the style is not explicitly defined

Tags: css, dom, browser

I am really curious.  You can obtain the z-index from an element but If a page is "just built" without a definition of z-indices, how would that resolve.  How does the browser do it?  Can we access this via javascript to obtain the browsers definition of the z-index instead of using the computer style component?

Why am i asking?  Well, style returns AUTO a loot, but i am curious as to what "auto" is according to the browser etc.

Comment: If no z-index is set, it defaults to auto, which means the elements are shown in the order they are added to the DOM, with certain exceptions based on position etc.

Comment: that makes sense to some extent, but one would think that there could be a numeric identifier for that DOM ordering.

Comment: Is this really a JavaScript question? Seems like more of a browser question.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/introduction.html

Comment: The DOM **is** the ordering.

Comment: i thought it could be a javascript question if my goal is to access it VIA javascript. but it seems that my answer uiss resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the browser do it?

It simply follows the CSS spec as described in [section 9.9](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers). In particular:

> **auto**
>   The stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context is 0. The box does not establish a new stacking context unless it is the root element.

And:

> Each box belongs to one *stacking context*. Each positioned box in a given stacking context has an integer *stack level*, which is its position on the z-axis relative other stack levels within the same stacking context. Boxes with greater stack levels are always formatted in front of boxes with lower stack levels. Boxes may have negative stack levels. Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order.

As for how to actually obtain the stack level for a given element, I don't think the DOM exposes this information because it's more of a CSS implementation detail than anything else (plus it would be zero anyway for all non-positioned elements with auto `z-index`, because it is a relative value and not an absolute one). And as already mentioned this information is not available through `getComputedStyle()` either.

Answer (score 2):

There is a natural stacking order that the browser use to determine how elements stack

> Below is a list showing the order that items fit into a stacking
>   context, starting with the bottom of the stack. This list assumes none
>   of the items has z-index applied:
>
> - Background and borders of the element that establish stacking context
> - Elements with negative stacking contexts, in order of appearance
> - Non-positioned, non-floated, block-level elements, in order of
>     appearance
> - Non-positioned, floated elements, in order of appearance
> - Inline elements, in order of appearance
> - Positioned elements, in order
>     of appearance

For more information check out: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/